# Can't use OpenPGP key exported from GnuPG with SSH

Tags: ssh, gpg, ssh-agent

I generated a PGP key with GnuPG over a year ago. Since I haven't had to really touch it since, I'm extremely foggy on the ins and outs of GPG (though I understand asymmetric key encryption in principle). I had used this key to authenticate SSH logins, right up until accidentally deleted it yesterday. So, today, I set out to generate it again.

I run `gpg --export-secret-key -a "Ryan Lue" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, and it prompts me for a password. I enter the password, and out comes the `id_rsa` file. Now, when I try to SSH into my servers, it throws the following warning:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

So, I obediently `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Then, I try again, and it prompts for a password (actually, since I'm on a Mac, Keychain prompts me for a password). I enter the same password I used to export it, and each time, it fails, spitting out the following error on the command line:

```
Saving password to keychain failed
```

I've also tried adding the key using `ssh-agent`, and that actually prompts me for the password on the command line:

```
Enter passphrase for /Users/rlue/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

Either way, it keeps rejecting the password. I'm 100% sure I'm entering the same passphrase at these prompts as I do to export it: I've successfully exported the key about a dozen times and failed to authenticate it in use about four dozen times.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenPGP (as implemented by GnuPG) and SSH do not share a common key format, although they rely on the same cryptographic principles.

GnuPG implements the `ssh-agent` protocol, though, so you can still use your OpenPGP keys through GnuPG for SSHing into other computers.

1. enable the `ssh-agent` protocol by adding `enable-ssh-support` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`
2. `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh`; you might want to do that in your `~/.profile`
3. kill `ssh-agent` if started and reload `gpg-agent`  (`gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`)
4. export and add your public key to target servers (`ssh-add -L` should now contain the familiar SSH public key line for your OpenPGP key)
5. `ssh` to the target server as with a normal SSH key

This also works great with OpenPGP smartcards or USB dongles, I'm using this to protect my SSH key with a YubiKey.

Comment: Thank you Jens! Somehow I missed your answer until now, and discovered all these things the hard way myself. :\ There were some additional steps that I needed to do to make it work (like adding the authentication key keygrip to `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` rather than exporting it); I [documented the process on my blog](http://ryanlue.com/posts/2017-06-29-gpg-for-ssh-auth) in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't see any option in [`gpg`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html) called `--export-secret-key`.

2) The key would probably have different format then expected by the `ssh`. You will most probably need to convert it to the format understood by OpenSSH. Update the question with the information in which format the key is.

Comment: 1) `--export-secret-key` is an alias for `--export-secret-keys`. It's not listed in the man page, but you can try it and see that it works yourself. 2) Thanks. gnupg.org states that gpg-agent can substitute ssh-agent, so I'm exploring that path atm...

Comment: 1) thanks for clarification. 2) It can substitute the ssh-agent for ssh-agent operations, but the format of used keys can be different.

Comment: 2) All of these similarly named projects, products, and protocols are making my head spin. It appears that [SSH protocol v2 has supported PGP key authentication since 2002](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/excerpt/ssh_8/) (although configuration is different from SSH1-style `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`); whether that means OpenSSH does, I'm still not sure.

Comment: So do not make your life harder with gpg-agent generate simple ssh key and use it. The GPG keys were supported in some ancient versions of SSH, but they are certainly not supported now.

Comment: This is working functionality provided by GnuPG 2.1 (the latest version), [documented from at least as far back as 2012](https://budts.be/weblog/2012/08/ssh-authentication-with-your-pgp-key). You're right that it would be easier to just generate a separate SSH key, though.

Comment: But in that guide there are much more steps than you present in the question including the conversion from gpg to ssh!

Comment: FYI, I saw that [you commented on a similar thread on the Ubuntu StackExchange last year](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732581/gpg-agent-and-ssh-no-keys/930105#930105). To clarify, GPG 2.1 does **not** require you to convert to a different format (or even export your keys) to authenticate SSH connections. I figured it out just half a day after Jens dropped the answer in my lap (above).